# Using a dummy HttpContext to Render a View to a string from a singleton in an ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, singleton

I have a requirement to render a view to a string from a singleton class in an asp.net application. The problem is that the singleton class does not have a http context, and so I am unable to create a controller context to generate the string.

I am using Rick Strahl's example to create a dummy controller context. But since that uses HttpContext.Current, I am creating a dummy HttpContext and using that. It works, and I am able to render the view as a string. But I dont know of the cons of using a dummy HttpContext. Please let me know if this is a good approach, or if there is another approach to be used when there is no current Http Context. Thanks!

```
public static T CreateController<T>(RouteData routeData = null)
        where T : Controller, new()
    {
        // create a disconnected controller instance
        T controller = new T();
        HttpContext ctx = new HttpContext(
        new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""),
        new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
        );

        // User is logged in
        ctx.User = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity("username"),
            new string[0]
            );           

        // get context wrapper from HttpContext if available
        HttpContextBase wrapper = null;
        if (ctx != null)
            wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(ctx);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Can't create Controller Context if no active HttpContext instance is available.");            

        if (routeData == null)
            routeData = new RouteData();

        // add the controller routing if not existing
        if (!routeData.Values.ContainsKey("controller") && !routeData.Values.ContainsKey("Controller"))
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", controller.GetType().Name
                                                        .ToLower()
                                                        .Replace("controller", ""));

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(wrapper, routeData, controller);
        return controller;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be singleton ?

Comment: It needs to be a singleton because I am building html and broadcasting to all the client browsers using signalr. So I want only 1 instance of this object running for the application.